# How to extract specific digit from pandas column using regex?

Tags: python, pandas, regex

Given the following column in pandas dataframe:

```
Name: Hockey Canada; NAICS: 711211

Name: Hockey Canada; NAICS: 711211

Name: International AIDS Society; NAICS: 813212

Name: Rogers Communications Inc; NAICS: 517112, 551112; Name: Hockey Canada; NAICS: 711211

Name: Health Benefits Trust; NAICS: 524114; Name: Hockey Canada; NAICS: 711211; Name: National Equity Fund; NAICS: 523999, 531110
```

I'd like to extract the NAICS code from each row (where they exist) in the pandas column. The desired result is indicated in column "expected_result".

```
711211
711211
813212

517112; 551112; 711211

524114; 711211; 523999; 531110
```

I have `NaN` in some rows please any suggestion using regex and python will be very helpful. I tried the regex `findall` function but I got an error.

I write this function:

```py
def find_number(text):
    num = re.findall(r'[0-9]+',text)
    return " ".join(num)
```

I used it in `apply` function like :

```py
df['NAICS']=df['Company'].apply(lambda x: find_number(x))
```

I got this error:

```
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [81], in <cell line: 1>() ----> 1 df['NAICS']=df['Company'].apply(lambda x: find_number(x))
```

Comment: If you could please, copy and paste your text as text into the question. You can use markdown formatting or the editor buttons at the top to format properly. Pasting text/tables as images is frowned upon as links die and no one wants to transcribe a picture to replicate on their machine.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Something like the following should get you in the ballpark: `re.findall(r'[0-9]*$', 'Big String with a number at the end: 711211')[0]`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: But what was it you tried? What's the error?

Comment: I write this function : ```def find_number(text):
    num = re.findall(r'[0-9]+',text)
    return " ".join(num)``` and I used after apply function like : ```df['NAICS']=df['Company'].apply(lambda x: find_number(x))```

Comment: I got this error: ```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [81], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df['NAICS']=df['Company'].apply(lambda x: find_number(x))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's likely some code golfy or more dataframe-friendly way to pull this off, but the overall logic will look something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

NAICSdf = pd.DataFrame(['Name: Hockey Canada; NAICS: 711211','Name: Hockey Canada; NAICS: 711211','Name: International AIDS Society; NAICS: 813212','Name: Rogers Communications Inc; NAICS: 517112, 551112; Name: Hockey Canada; NAICS: 711211','Name: Health Benefits Trust; NAICS: 524114; Name: Hockey Canada; NAICS: 711211; Name: National Equity Fund; NAICS: 523999, 531110'], columns=['organization'], )

def findNAICS(organization):
    NAICSList = []
    for found in re.findall(r'NAICS:\s[0-9, ]*', organization):
        for NAICS in found.split(': ')[1].split(', '):
            NAICSList.append(NAICS)
    return '; '.join(NAICSList)

NAICSdf['NAICS'] = NAICSdf['organization'].apply(findNAICS)
print(NAICSdf)
```

That will create a new column in your dataframe with a semicolon delimited list of NAICS codes from your string.

Comment: Thanks, @Wiktor, the code works. But for the last proposed by JNevill I got this error : ```    240     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 241     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object```

Comment: Wiktor's answer is exactly what I was shooting for. He moved some of the logic back into the regex and then pushed everything back up to the dataframe without `apply()` needing to be in the mix. Ultimately that's a cleaner way to pull this off. The benefit with this `apply()` method is that all of the logic for splitting out these values is held in a function where it's a little easier to understand and maintain, but it might not be as speedy.

Comment: that's true. I found why I got an error with Wiktor's suggestion, and the code works correctly now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
df['expected_result'] = df['organization'].astype(str).str.findall(r'\bNAICS:\s*(\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*)').str.join(' ').str.findall(r'\d+').str.join("; ")
```

*Details*:

- `.str.findall(r'\bNAICS:\s*(\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*)')` - find all comma separated numbers after `NAICS:`
- `.str.join(' ')` - joins the found matches with a space
- `.str.findall(r'\d+')` - extracts numbers separately
- `.str.join("; ")` - joins them with `;` and space.

See a Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'organization':['NAICS: 12342; NAICS: 55555, 66667', 'NAICS:9999']})
df['expected_result'] = df['organization'].astype(str).str.findall(r'\bNAICS:\s*(\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*)').str.join(' ').str.findall(r'\d+').str.join("; ")
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                        organization      expected_result
0  NAICS: 12342; NAICS: 55555, 66667  12342; 55555; 66667
1                         NAICS:9999                 9999
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to sort this by regex then you can do this:
It simply looks for the recurrence of 6 digits combined together. As it seems like there are some cases of NAICS having multiple records in a row i didn't go more precise. That might cause some inaccuracy if the data involves other records with 6 digit groupings.

```
str1 = 'Name: Hockey Canada; NAICS: 711211'
str2 = 'Name: Rogers Communications Inc; NAICS: 517112, 551112; Name: Hockey Canada; NAICS: 711211'

data = [str1, str2]
results = [re.findall('\d{6}', entry) for entry in data]

print(results)
```

Ouput:

```
[['711211'], ['517112', '551112', '711211']]
```

You might also want to change the delimiter if needed, depending on how you intend on processing the data before entering it into the records. And the list stores a list of hits per row so this can be sorted as you see fit.